# Expand a vector by semicolon in some elements in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector in R:

```
x<-c("a", "b", "c;d", "e", "f;g;h;i;j")
```

My question is how to expand `x` by the seperator ";", namely a desired output would be:

```
 x
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `strsplit`:

```
unlist(strsplit(x, split = ";"))
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
```